# JPA 2.0 JPQL Update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am facing a different behaviour of hibernate update, I am running a simple JPQL to update the workpool of my tasks and its firing `select-insert` and `bulk-update` queries to update my task's workpool.

Below is my method to move my task to workpool:

```
public Boolean changeWorkpool(final TaskWorkpoolChangeRequest taskWorkpoolChangeRequest) {
final Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Task SET workpoolId = :workpoolId"
    + " WHERE taskId= :taskId");
query.setParameter("workpoolId", taskWorkpoolChangeRequest.getWorkpoolId())
    .setParameter("taskId", taskWorkpoolChangeRequest.getTaskId());
return BooleanUtils.toBoolean(query.executeUpdate());
```

}

Here are the queries executing on the server:

```
Hibernate: /* select insert */ insert into HT_task select task0_.task_id as task_id 
from task task0_ left outer join task_manager manager0_1_ on task0_.task_id=manager0_1_.task_id 
left outer join task_employee employee0_2_ on task0_.task_id=employee0_2_.task_id 
where task0_.task_id=?

Hibernate: /* bulk update */ update task set workpool_id=? where (task_id) 
IN (select task_id from HT_task)
```

Is it the expected behaviour of hibernate to execute update queries or am i missing anything?

Can anyone please give some pointers on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a decent explanation of the bulk operations in java here:
http://in.relation.to/2072.lace